# Is it possible to create a query matching the same document on MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I have a document that looks like this:

```json
{
    "total": 150.00,
    "products": [
        {"a": 75.00},
        {"b": 75.00}
    ],
    "paid": 100.00
}
```

I'm trying to find a way to query a document where the `total` is greater than the `paid` field.

So far I've tried:

```
db.find(...)

{paid: {$lt: "$total"}}
{paid: {$lt: "$total"}}
{paid: {$lt: "$$this.total"}}

{total: {$gt: "$paid"}}
{total: {$gt: "$$this.paid"}}

{$where: "this.total > this.paid"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [$expr](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) expression operator to match internal fields and [$gt](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gt/) aggregation operator to check condition,

```
{ $expr: { $gt: ["$total", "$paid"] } }
```